# Delete multiple rows matching id - MVC Asp.Net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've a Category table

```
CategoryId | CategoryName | ParentID

    1      |    Men's     |   NULL 
    2      |   Women's    |   NULL 
    3      |   Mobile     |   NULL 
    4      |  Computing   |   NULL 
    5      | Electronics  |   NULL 
    6      |    Other     |   NULL 
    7      |    Shirt     |   1 
    8      |   T-Shirt    |   1 
    9      |   Dresses    |   2 
    10     |     Tops     |   2 
    11     |    Nokia     |   3
    12     |   Samsung    |   3 
    13     | Other Mobiles|   3 
    14     |    Apple     |   13 
    15     |     Sony     |   13
```

As you can see, Categories which have `NULL` ParentID value are Top Categories and then there are SubCategories of that Category.

I want to delete categories, If I delete Top Category all of its SubCategories must also be deleted. If SubCategory get deleted then Top Category stay.

I'm able to delete each category separately by:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete (int id) {
    Category cat = db.Categories.Find(id);
    db.Categories.Remove(cat)
    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: Did you look at nested sets?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete (int id) {
    Category cat = db.Categories.Find(id);
    var subCategories = db.Categories.Where(a => a.ParentId == id);        
    db.Categories.RemoveAll(subCategories);
    db.Categories.Remove(cat)

    return View("Index");
}
```

Method name of RemoveAll may vary based on what you are using. names are different LinqToSql and EntityFramework. I guess you got the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use a recursive function to handle more than 2 levels of hierachy.

```
public void DeleteCategoryRecursive(int id)
{ 
    var parent = db.Categories.Find(id);
    var children = db.Categories.Where(a => a.ParentID == parent.CategoryID).ToList();
    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        DeleteCategoryRecursive(child.CategoryID);
    }
    db.Categories.Remove(parent);
}
```

then call this from your ActionResult.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete (int id) {
    DeleteCategoryRecursive(int id);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View("Index");
}
```